# Firestore save of new document doesn't call error if no internet connection can be made

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

The following code snippet runs on my iPhone and works perfectly with the phone on WiFi but if I turn airplane mode on, the callback is never called.  I'm looking for error to have a value as well. Once I turn airplane mode off, the call back is made.

I really would like to know immediately if the document could not be saved because of a lack of network connectivity.

```
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            let settings = FirestoreSettings()
            settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
            db.collection("CachingTestCollection").document(UUID().uuidString).setData(["test": "document"]){ (error: Error?) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error)")
                } else {
                    print("document saved successfully")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is actually he expected behavior: not having an internet connection is not an error condition for Firestore, as it can work perfectly fine with just its local cache.

The completion handler you attach will only be called once the data is committed on the server however. If you want to know when the data has been stored locally, that has happened as soon as the call to `setData` returns without raising an error.

So:

```
db.collection("CachingTestCollection").document(UUID().uuidString).setData(["test": "document"])
print("Document was written locally")
```

Or:

```
db.collection("CachingTestCollection").document(UUID().uuidString).setData(["test": "document"]){ (error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error)")
    } else {
        print("document was saved on the server successfully")
    }
}
print("Document was written locally")
```

Typically, if you want to display the state of the data in your app, it is better to [use a realtime listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), [listen for metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) and then look at the [snapshot metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot#metadata) for the document.

Comment: Interesting.  I was thinking that setting the isPersistenceEnabled to false would prevent it from saving locally and just error out if no internet.  I was then going to handle my own caching.  I have notice data that should be sent to firestore not showing up after internet disconnection and then reconnection so was going to implement my own caching.